# Multiplication between two different dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a multiplication between two dictionary:

```
quantita_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [1.0]}
prezzo_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [100.0], '70cm* 2cm': [100.0],}
```

I want to get a `result` variable as a multiplication for all keys that matches between the two dictionaries.

I have tried to get the following code:

```
result={k : v * prezzo_materiale[k] for k, v in quantita_materiale.items() if k in prezzo_materiale}
```

But python gives me the following error:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying with a string with a list. That would definitely give a runtime error. You should instead be doing it as follows -

```
quantita_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [1.0]}
prezzo_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [100.0], '70cm* 2cm': [100.0],}

result={k : v[0] * int(prezzo_materiale[k][0]) for k, v in quantita_materiale.items() if k in prezzo_materiale}

print(result)
print("total - ",total)
```

**Output :**

```
{'140cm* 2cm': 100.0}
total - 100.0
```

---

The above method would only work if your values has only 1 element in the list. However, if you want it to work for values with lists having multiple elements, then you can use the following code -

```
quantita_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [1.0,2.0]}
prezzo_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [100.0,200.0], '70cm* 2cm': [100.0],}

result ={}
for k in quantita_materiale.keys():
    if k in prezzo_materiale:
        result[k] = [v1*v2 for v1,v2 in zip(quantita_materiale[k],prezzo_materiale[k])]
        
print(result)
total = sum(sum(result.values(),[]))
print("total",total)
```

**Output :**

```
{'140cm* 2cm': [100.0, 400.0]}
total 500.0
```

**DO NOTE:**

The first version of the answer won't work if the input has any value for a key that has more than one element in the list. So, the 2nd version of my answer would work for following inputs as well -

**INPUT :**

```
quantita_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [1.0,2.0],'70cm* 2cm':[5.0]}
prezzo_materiale={'140cm* 2cm': [100.0,200.0], '70cm* 2cm': [100.0]}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
{'140cm* 2cm': [100.0, 400.0], '70cm* 2cm': [500.0]}
total 1000.0
```

Comment: ohhh thanks, and If I want to sum all value in result?

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco by sum, do you mean sum each value of different key into one or each sum the list of values for each key?

Comment: sum each value of different key into one

Comment: I have tried `total_costo_materiale={'Costi Materiale': [sum(t) for t in zip(*result.values())]}` but give me 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco I have included the total for first case

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco Check the answer now. I have added how to sum for both of the cases

Answer (score 1):

`result={k : v[0] * prezzo_materiale[k][0] for k, v in quantita_materiale.items() if k in prezzo_materiale}`

when you try to get
`k, v for quantita_materiale.items()`, you get `k is str key`, and `v is a list containing 1 number`, so if you want to get access to number you need to get first item of list that is `v[0]`, the same is for `prezzo_materiale[k]`

this will give you a

```
result = {
 '140cm* 2cm': 100.0
}
```

if you want to have same result (`list of integer`)? you need to use this code:

```
    result={
        k : [v[0] * prezzo_materiale[k][0]] for k, v in quantita_materiale.items()  if k in prezzo_materiale
    }
```

it will returns

```
result = {
 '140cm* 2cm': [100.0]
}
```

Comment: Though your answer may be correct, it is much more helpful if you add some explanation.

Comment: modified answer

Comment: ohhh thanks, and If I want to sum all value in result?

Comment: `sum_total = sum(result.values())` if you use 1 variant and `sum_total = sum(number[0] for number in result.values())` for second variant

Comment: This answer **Won't Work** if the input has an value which has more than one element in the list.